# Is there any way to link project analysis results (running Sonar Scanner) to developers?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Indeed, I have found Developer Cockpit Plugin which is commercial one. But I would like to know is there any alternative with simple features (None Commercial) to apply?

Answer (score 1):

Use an SCM Plugin (e.g. [Git Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin)) and you'll immediately benefit from the [auto-assign feature](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment): if the committer of a line with an issue matches a SonarQube user account, issue will be automatically assigned to that user (who can see his issues from his [User Account](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Account)). Not to mention all the issue filtering that you can then do by *author*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was very helpful. I am trying to integrate LDAP into Sonar, but I couldnt get enough material from Sonar.org in order configure the properties. I did some configuration but it is not working. Can you help me out in this one: Here is my sonar Property set: sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.url=ldap://192.168.100.2
ldap.user.baseDn=cu=Users,dc=corebanking,dc=tejaratbank,dc=local
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

Comment: You need to open another thread for your LDAP issue (and please provide more information about what is not working and server's logs). Thanks